# Minimum API for implementing Android Deep Linking

Tags: android, deep-linking

I follow [Android official tutorial](https://io2015codelabs.appspot.com/codelabs/android-deep-linking#1) for implementing android deep linking. Here is the requirement for this tutorial:

```
Android Studio version 1.0+
The sample code
The Google app version 2.8+
A test device with Android 4.1+
A USB micro to USB cable.
```

So base on this, I can understand minimum API for deep linking is Android 4.1 (API >= 17). But after I follow, I really don't see any functions that use API>=17. You just register in `manifest.xml` file and handle in activity, done.

So my question is:  Can I implement Android Deep linking at older android such as android 2.3.3.

Thanks :)

Comment: The actual portion of that tutorial that relates to deep linking (`intent-filter`) was introduced at API level 1. Therefore, you should be able to add the logic to your manifest for apps that support older versions.

Comment: @dharms thanks. I think like you that this important point is using `intent-filter`.  But because they say test device with 4.1+ (they don't say this is minimum), and I don't have real device with lower API for testing :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no API there that requires API 17. However, the version of Google Search that enables deep linking *does* require API 17, hence why you must use an API17+ device to test deep linking.

Comment: I tested deep linking in various way. For example, typing a link in email, in a note ... and click through this link. This work (on Android 4.4). So the way you go to some links not always using Google Search.  So we still need API 17+ ? thanks :)

Comment: Only if you want to do [App Indexing](https://developers.google.com/app-indexing/), the [next step after the code lab](https://io2015codelabs.appspot.com/codelabs/android-deep-linking#10)